# One specific wifi network does not work & Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

One specific network does not work for my Ubuntu 20.02 laptop. This is my main home wifi network. On the other hand I can connect to other home Wifi networks (but the signal of the latter networks is poor).

**The wifi connection that does not work is called "Ziggo-ap-4a3dc0b".** This wifi connection  perfectly works on my Android smartphone and on my Windows desktop pc, but it does not work on my laptop. I cannot connect to "Ziggo-ap-4a3dc0b" with my laptop.

**The problem is now solved. There were problems with the router. The settings of the router are now correct, and the wifi connection works.**

Then I used `iwlist wlp2s0 scanning` in the terminal. The output is reported below. I report both the output for the network that does not work "Ziggo-ap-4a3dc0b", and I report the output for the network that works "Ziggo0382799":

````
          Cell 01 - Address: 18:35:D1:35:21:C7
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo0382799"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001b33089f25a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4196ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C5A6967676F30333832373939
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030124
                    IE: Unknown: 073C4555202401172801172C01173001173401173801173C011740011764011E68011E6C011E70011E74011E78011E7C011E80011E84011E88011E8C011E
                    IE: Unknown: 460573D000000C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF091BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1624050400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0805000F0200000040
                    IE: Unknown: BF0CB2018033EAFF0000EAFF0000
                    IE: Unknown: C005012A00FCFF
                    IE: Unknown: C30402D2D2D2
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010098F6F4876815770B0A001E3963000DD1021001C41746865726F7320436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E732C20496E632E102300044150787810240008415078782D7878781042001253657269616C204E756D62657220486572651054000800060050F20400011011000941746865726F734150100800020104103C0001021049000600372A000120```



```Cell 02 - Address: 34:E8:94:A3:DC:0B
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo-ap-4a3dc0b"
                    Bit Rates:11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                              48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000001ced8ea1
                    Extra: Last beacon: 10072ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00105A6967676F2D61702D34613364633062
                    IE: Unknown: 01079618243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B00010310470010123456789ABCDEF0123434E894A3DC0B1021000754502D4C494E4B10230018457874726120776966692D70756E74205A6967676F20433710240003322E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220417263686572204337100800022008103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK```



Then I used ```tail -f /var/log/syslog```, and the output is: 

```Dec 31 20:34:01 nico-Nitro-AN515-51 kernel: [  656.978153] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by c6:c9:e3:27:55:c3``` 

```Dec 31 20:34:01 nico-Nitro-AN515-51 wpa_supplicant[867]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-86 noise=-100 txrate=6000```


I also used ```sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager```. These warnings were shown in the terminal: 

```NetworkManager[825]: <warn> [1609442589.4993] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist``` 

```<warn>  [1609442589.9571] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate``` 

```<warn>  [1609442590.0718] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed.```




**What can I do to make my main home Wifi network work?**
````

Comment: What is the wireless channel that you can't connect to?

Comment: It would be useful to know what type of wireless network you are tying to connect to - unencrypted, WEP, WPA, WPA2 (CCMP or TKIP), or 802.1x - and whether any of the previous networks you have sucessfully connected to use the same configuration. You can find out more by using the `iwlist` utility in Ubuntu and reading the output. Also check your router's setting page.

Comment: Can you see any useful relevant output in any of the log files (try: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, try connecting - and see if any useful failure messages are printed)

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: @Mark: i used iwlist in the terminal. This is the output: ```Usage: iwlist [interface] scanning [essid NNN] [last]
              [interface] frequency 
              [interface] channel 
              [interface] bitrate 
              [interface] rate 
              [interface] encryption 
              [interface] keys 
              [interface] power 
              [interface] txpower 
[interface] retry 
 [interface] ap 
 [interface] accesspoints 
 [interface] peers 
 [interface] event 
 [interface] auth 
 [interface] wpakeys 
 [interface] genie

Comment: @Mark: I just used ```tail -f /var/log/syslog```. This is the output: 

```Dec 31 20:34:01 nico-Nitro-AN515-51 kernel: [  656.978153] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by c6:c9:e3:27:55:c3
Dec 31 20:34:01 nico-Nitro-AN515-51 wpa_supplicant[867]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-86 noise=-100 txrate=6000```

Comment: @waltinator: Hi, I used ```sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager```. Here I report only the warnings: ``` NetworkManager[825]: <warn>  [1609442589.4993] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist``` ```<warn>  [1609442589.9571] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate``` ```<warn>  [1609442590.0718] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed```.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator: I added my comments directly in the question.

Comment: Apologies, when I said use iwlist, I though you might read the man page, rather than just posting the usage output. `iwlist wlp2s0 scanning` will give you output of all the networks that your card can find, including signal strength and connection settings. Update the quesiton with that information, rather than just copying and pasting the usage information. Are you getting any error or failure messages at all?

Comment: @Mark: I added the output of ```iwlist wlp2s0 scanning``` in my question.

Comment: The network you can connect to successfully is 5ghz, the one you are having problems with is 2.4ghz. have you previously connected to a 2.4ghz network without problems, on this machine?